# Read 4 lines at a time, in parallel, from text file

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have these two data sets:

data1.txt:

```
@SRR14820084.1 A00794:192:HJNGKDRXX:1:1101:1208:1047/1
CCCCCCTCTCACGGGCTTCTCGGACACAAACGGGAAGGCACACAGCCAGACGGAGCACCGGAGGCACACCAGGGAATGGGAAGCGCCACCACCAGCTCAGAAGCA
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF::F:FFF:F,F:,FFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF:FFFF,FFFFF,FFFFF,FF,FFFFFFFFFF,FF:
@SRR14820084.2 A00794:192:HJNGKDRXX:1:1101:1371:1047/1
ATCCATTTATGGTTCTGACAAAACACACTCACCATAGATACTCATGATAGATTTGTTTTTAATTATTAAAAAACTGAAATACAACCTAGGTAGTGGTAGCATACA
+
FFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF::FFFFF:FFFFF:FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFF:,FFFFFFFFFF,FF:FF:
```

data2.txt

```
@SRR14820084.1 A00794:192:HJNGKDRXX:1:1101:1208:1047/2
GGTTTGTCTCCTAGGTGCCTGCTTCTGAGCTGGTGGTGGCGCTTCCCATTCCCTGGTGTGCCTCCGGTGCTCCGTCTGGCTGTGTGCCTTCCCGTTTGTGTCCGA
+
F:FFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFF
@SRR14820084.2 A00794:192:HJNGKDRXX:1:1101:1371:1047/2
CAAGATTTCTCTGTGTAGTCTTGTCTGTCCTGGAACTAGCTATGTAGACCAGGCTAGTCTTGAACTCACAGAAGTCCACCTGCTTCTGCCTCCTGAGTGCTAGGA
+
F::FF:FFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,FFFF,FFFFFFFFFFF:F::FFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFF
```

The goal of my script is to do something on the first 4 lines, then the 5th to 8th lines, etc. on these two files.

I do this with this function:

```
def process_read_pairs(input_file_1, input_file_2):
    total_read_pairs = 0
    
    out_file1 = "dataset1_out.txt"
    out_file2 = "dataset2_out.txt"
    
    with open(input_file_1, 'r') as file1, open(input_file_2, 'r') as file2, open(out_file1, 'w') as output_file1, open(out_file2, 'w') as output_file2:
        while True:
            ### Read four lines at a time of each read pair ###
            
            # Read first line of each read pair (i.e. name)
            name1 = file1.readline().strip()
            name2 = file2.readline().strip()
            
            # Stop if end of file is reached
            if not name1 or not name2:
                break
            
            # Read second line of each read pair (i.e. sequence)
            seq1 = file1.readline().strip()
            seq2 = file2.readline().strip()
                        
            # Read third line of each read pair (i.e. +)
            plus1 = file1.readline().strip()
            plus2 = file2.readline().strip()

            # Read fourth line of each read pair (i.e. quality)
            quality1 = file1.readline().strip()
            quality2 = file2.readline().strip()
            
            
            # Here would be some code that would manipulate the lines that would be read
            ...
            ...

            
            # Write read pair to output files (each on a separate line)
            # read1
            output_file1.write(f"{name1}\n"
            output_file1.write(f"{read1}\n"
            output_file1.write(f"{plus1}\n"
            output_file1.write(f"{quality1}\n"
                
            #read2
            output_file2.write(f"{read2}\n"
            output_file2.write(f"{read2}\n"
            output_file2.write(f"{plus2}\n"
            output_file2.write(f"{quality2}\n"
```

This works well. The only problem is that it is quite slow (the actual data files can be up to 40GB).

I want to parallelise the `while` loop. One way would be to read all the lines at once using `readlines()` and assign different sections of all the lines to different parallel processes, but this would require a lot of memory.

Is there a way to parallelise the current `while` loop without reading all the data into memory?

The important thing to keep in mind is that for both files the same lines would have to be read (the data is paired), but in the output it would not matter if for example the first 4 lines come last and lines 5 to 8 first (as long as it is the same for both data sets).

Comment: The actual reading is so fast that there's no point to parallelizing it -- the overhead would overwhelm any benefit you might otherwise gain. Remember, to read the second line you first need to know how long the first line is -- so the operations have an inherent order.

Comment: It would make much more sense to have a process that _in serial_ reads groups of four lines and throws them onto a work queue, and a process _in parallel_ (whether via a threadpool or otherwise) that handles content from that queue.

Comment: In general, I'd also suggest (1) benchmarking with a sampling profiler to be sure you know where your time is actually being spent in practice; and (2) being open to considering tools other than Python, if an unacceptable amount of time _really is_ being spent in the I/O itself.

Comment: slow compared to ? what is your hard disk speed ? what is the current program read and write speed ? how much work are you doing every few lines ? what is the core's load % ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your suggestions. I was not familiar with these, so now I can learn about them.